# Induction and Fibonacci

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

The problem is this:

Prove by using induction that the Fibonacci equation has the solution

$\ F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$

Yeah I know for example you start with the very first n = 1 and then you try for any given n =p and the last part where n = p +1 I dont get how to do the last part

Comment: What have you tried?  Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2293969/recurrence-relation-for-fibonacci-sequence)

Comment: Do you know what induction means? Can you, for example, write out the induction hypothesis?

Comment: Yeah I know for example you start with the very first n = 1 and then you try for any given n =p and the last part where n = p +1 I dont get how to do the last part

Comment: I think here it's a little trickier because each Fibonacci number depends on the previous two, so you have to show it's true for the first *two* and then show that if it's true for two consecutive numbers then it's true for the next

Comment: oh yeah you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sketch would be...

Show that $f_1 = 1$ and $f_2 = 1$

This covers your base cases.

Take note that $\left(\frac {1+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^2= 1+\frac {1+\sqrt 5}{2}$ and $\left(\frac {1-\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^2= 1+\frac {1-\sqrt 5}{2}$

This will be useful in proving the inductive step.

Suppose for all $k\le n, f_k = F_k.$  This is "strong induction."

$F_{k+1} = F_k + F_{k-1}$ by the definition of the Fibonacci sequence

If we can show that $f_n+f_{n-1} = f_{n+1}$ then we are done.  We will that when it is true for all $k\le n$ we can extend that to all $k\le n+1$ and keep extending that indefinitely.

The rest is just algebra.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help was able to sovle my problem

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let $\phi=\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}2$ and $\psi=\dfrac{1-\sqrt5}2$.

Can you show $\phi^2=\phi+1$ and $\psi^2=\psi+1$,

so $\phi^{n+1}=\phi^{n}+\phi^{n-1}$ and $\psi^{n+1}=\psi^n+\psi^{n-1}$,

so $\dfrac{\phi^{n+1}-\psi^{n+1}}{\sqrt5}=\dfrac{\phi^{n}-\psi^{n}}{\sqrt5}+\dfrac{\phi^{n-1}-\psi^{n-1}}{\sqrt5}$?